# download link issue in IE-8

Tags: php, html

Hello I have added download sample file link in my project.
This is what I done for that:-

```
<a href="<?php echo HTTP_PATH; ?>sample_user_invitation.csv" style="color:#00f">Download Sample File</a>
```

Note:HTTP_PATH is constant  for define file path

It seems to work fine in all browser but not working in IE-8.In iE-8 when I try to download it shows all contain of file in browser. 
any suggestion will appreciate.

Comment: I have a bug in my current project. How to fix it? Any suggestion will be appreciated. You have to be more specific. **Why** doesn't it work in IE8? Is the URL valid?

Comment: What is the content of `HTTP_PATH` ?

Comment: sorry for that h2oooooo

Comment: @user3337415 There's no need to be so rude to someone who's just trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to create another page with correct meta-tag to help browser managing file as a download one.

Your code does not order to download a file but ask any single browser to perform their own default action with "csv" file. IE 8 lacks in this feature.

So any download link must to call a php function that sets the page with this headers:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' .$HTTP_PATH. $fileName. '"');
```

if you need a tutorial, look [here](http://www.webinfopedia.com/php-file-download-script.html)